# img src and thumbnails not clicking

Tags: php, image, html, onclick

**When I build this loop, my image and thumbnails display, however, I can't get my onClick function to rebuild the main image with the value of the onClick**

```
if($Image_Count > 0){
    $structure = "./images/$City_R/$Zip_Code_R/$StreetDirection $StreetName/$StreetNumber $StreetDirection $StreetName $StreetSuffix $City_R $Zip_Code_R-1";
    $img = '<img src="'.$structure.'.jpeg" style="border-style:solid; border-width:10px; border-color:#fff; width=500px; id=Main_Image;"><br/>';     
            }else{
                $img = "";
            }

    $Count_Image=1;

    if($Image_Count > 1){

    while($Count_Image <= $Image_Count){

        if($Count_Image < 10){
            $Count_Image = ''.$Count_Image;
                    }
            $structure = "./images/$City_R/$Zip_Code_R/$StreetDirection $StreetName/$StreetNumber $StreetDirection $StreetName $StreetSuffix $City_R $Zip_Code_R-$Count_Image";                                        
            $img_Thumb .= "<img src=\"$structure.jpeg\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('Main_Image').src = '\$structure.jpeg' ;\" width=\"50px\" border=\"0\" style=\"border-style=:solid;border-width:2px;border-color:#fff;margin-right:0px;\">";

            $Count_Image++;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to get the `$structure` in `document.getElementById('Main_Image').src = '\$structure.jpeg' ;` replaced by the PHP variable value?

If so, I assume the `\` before the `$` is a mistake?

I would try the following

```
$img_Thumb .= "<img src=\"" . $structure . ".jpeg\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('Main_Image').src = '" . $structure . ".jpeg' ;\" width=\"50px\" border=\"0\" style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:2px;border-color:#fff;margin-right:0px;\">";
```

and in the first section I would change the following line (id is a HTML property, not CSS and CSS properties don't use `=`)

```
$img = '<img src="'.$structure.'.jpeg" style="border-style:solid; border-width:10px; border-color:#fff; width: 500px;" id="Main_Image"><br/>';
```

Comment: Tried both of these, neither works.  There is something wrong with the thumb definition, mouseover doesn't register in the id bar with the onClick property...

Comment: Aha, you also have another error, I'll edit to include in my answer